# how to produce Beep sound in Aspx using JS based on code behind action?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

simply I've .wav file and I want to run it once the textbox value changed. the textbox is placed on a aspx page. I've an HTML5 tag called  :

```
   <audio id="audiotag1" src="Sound/Alarm1.wav" preload="auto"></audio>    
<script type="text/javascript">
    function play_single_sound() {
        document.getElementById('audiotag1').play();
    }
</script>
```

and the code behind is:

```
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, GetType(Page), "Script", "play_single_sound();", True)
```

they work fine if the browser support HTML5. So, I need same thing using javascript so that it work with each browser.

thanks

Comment: You need to research on [audio fallback](http://matt.coneybeare.me/getting-html5-audio-tag-and-flash-fallback-to/), that is, using non-HTML5 audio to play sound. This is for browsers doesn't support the audio tag. also you have to realize that each browser [supports different media type](https://www.scirra.com/blog/44/on-html5-audio-formats-aac-and-ogg) (mp3, ogg, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Use this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function play_single_sound() {
        var audio = new Audio('Alarm1.wav');
        audio.play();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML
**Text box**
If you want to play sound in text change event then add onchange event to your text box control then in the corresponding function play the sound

```
 <input type="text" id="myTextBox"
        onchange="musicplay()">
```

Java script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function musicplay() {
        var Playsound= new Audio('Sound/Alarm1.wav');
        Playsound.play();
    }
</script>
```